# how to save files in python and automate it?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

while analysing a pandas dataframe which contain different filtering.After each filtering i want to plot the data and save it.

The plotting and saving is common for all filtering currently i am doing as follows:

*there are 10 filters*

```
def filter_file1()
    .
    #filtering conditions
    .
    .
     
    #Plotting

    X_ = new_df['Distanlce].min() -2 
    Y_ = new_df['Distanlce].max() +8 
    new_df.plot(x=RAM,y=RDM,kind='scatter',xlabel= 'Azimuth',ylabel= 'Distance',xlim = [-60,60],ylim=[X_,Y_])
    pl.title('TEST 3.1')
    pl.grid()
    pl.savefig('YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_1.png')

def filter_file2()
    .
    #filtering conditions
    .
    .
    #Plotting
    X_ = new_df['Distanlce].min() -2 
    Y_ = new_df['Distanlce].max() +8  
    new_df.plot(x=RAM,y=RDM,kind='scatter',xlabel= 'Azimuth',ylabel= 'Distance',xlim = [-60,60],ylim=[X_,Y_])
    pl.title('TEST 3.2')
    pl.grid()
    pl.savefig('YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_2.png')
```

Instead of this i want to create a *plot* function for plotting and saving it in this format YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_1.png, YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_2.png ...... YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_10.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to date each plot, you can use the built-in library time.

You can use something like this :

```
import time

def get_name_of_file(filter_index):
    time_ = time.gmtime(time.time())
    date = str(time_.tm_year)+str(time_.tm_mon)+str(time_.tm_mday)+"_SQ3_TC3_"+str(filter_index)+".png"
    return date
```

Comment: now i have the date but how i can automate saving the image with that

Comment: @mathew You can do for example in your second filter : `pl.savefig(get_name_of_file(2))` instead of `pl.savefig('YYYYMMDD_SQ3_TC3_2.png')`